# How do I create a window in OpenGL on Linux instead of using GLUT?

Tags: linux, opengl, glut

How do I create a window in OpenGL on Linux instead of using GLUT? Is there a performance penalty when using one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all, i want to ask if using glut is performance-wise.

It makes no difference for OpenGL performance, which framework you use to create the window.

> How can i do it?

You mean the long and hard way using X11 and GLX? I've example code for that here:

https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl/x11argb_opengl.c